Include book part title in header if one exists
I render a multipart book with Asciidoctor PDF.
In a page's header, I want to have the current book part and chapter, separated by –. If there is no book part (e.g. in preface or appendix) there should only be the chapter title.
I tried to use a conditional expression in my theme:
extends: default
header:
  height: 33pt
  recto: &header
    content-margin: [8pt, inherit, inherit, inherit]
    right:
      content: ifdef::part-title[{part-title} – ] {chapter-title}
  verso: *header

However, this just renders ifdef::part-title[ – ] as-is, without evaluating the conditional expression (while it does evaluate {part-title}).
How can I fix this to actually evaluate the conditional expression?
I also tried it with multi-line content:
extends: default
header:
  height: 33pt
  recto: &header
    content-margin: [8pt, inherit, inherit, inherit]
    right:
      content: |
        ifdef::part-title[]
          {part-title} –
        endif::[]
        {chapter-title}
  verso: *header

This also does get printed verbatim.

I have not tried this, so I don't know if it is the answer. The AsciiDoc conditional macros are line-oriented, and the content is not expressed in the square brackets. Take a look at https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/theme/add-running-content/#multi-line-values for example multi-line formatting of the content key, and https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/ifdef-ifndef/ for the markup of conditional macros.

@eskwayrd The third example in your second link does put the content in the square brackets, not sure what you mean by not expressed in the square brackets. I did try to use multiline content, edited the question to also show that. Sadly it doesn't work either.
